# Optimum memory split for a RasPi 2 streaming movies

Tags: pi-2, kodi, streaming-video, memory-split

What's the optimum memory split for a Raspberry Pi 2 with 1 GB of RAM streaming movies.

Answer (score 1):

This, unfortunately, isn't an easily answerable question. 'Optimal' depends to varying extents on what format your movies are in (i.e. how difficult the decoding is), what software you're using to receive your streams, what resolution your display is, what else you might be doing while streaming your movies, whether there are other clients streaming *from* the Pi, etc etc etc.

- Start with a high CPU/low GPU balance.
- Check your video playback
  performance.  If it's not what it should be, decrease CPU and
  increase GPU.
- Repeat until you arrive at a split you're happy with.